Extensions are installed, but Rainbow isn't recognizing them as installed in my extension
I am building a Chrome extension to connect Web3 wallets, and I am using RainbowKit for this purpose. When I run the project on the web, it shows the installed extensions like MetaMask and Phantom as recognized. However, when I load the extension in Chrome, it doesn't display the installed extensions, and there is no option to connect to the wallet through the MetaMask extension. I have to scan from my mobile instead of using the Chrome extension.
Running as web 

Loaded as extension in chrome

When I clicked on metamask to connect 

I tried changing different permissions in the manifest.json, and I expect the extension to be shown as installed since I already have it installed in my browser.
